# How to avoid prompting username and password in mozila

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Hi i am new to web application. i have deployed asp.net web application in IIS7.5. set windows authentication mode.if i browse the website in IE ,web site is not asking username and password, but if i browse in Mozilla its prompting username and password.

is there any way to avoid prompting username and password?